# Coding chess engine

Tags: engines, software, programming

I have always wanted to start coding a simple chess engine. I do have basic understanding about the general architecture of such a program, but I would love to see some examples first. 
Anyone have tried his hand in coding a chess engine? 
can you guys suggest good online resource that is clear and organized about how to start such a project?

Thanks

Comment: [here](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some very basic chess engines which are very instructive for a beginner chess programmer. The list can be found [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Category:Open_Source). This page is also has a lot of useful resources about chess programming, I recommend you to take your time reading articles on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [TSCP](http://www.tckerrigan.com/Chess/TSCP/) chess engine. The implementation is a plain alpha-beta with no optimisation, thus it'll be easy for you to study. Furthermore, the board representation is array-based (stronger engines usually use bitboard), so it shouldn't be a very challenging task for you to go through the move generation code.

Answer (score 2):

Chess programming wiki has good resources. https://www.chessprogramming.org/Recommended_Reading

Answer (score 1):

This engine was created just with the idea of being of help to beginners on the chess engines coding world:

https://github.com/emdio/secondchess